# User Profile Service Incremental Sync doesn't sync photos

Tags: user-profile-service

On a Sharepoint 2010 farm I've found lately that the automatic Incremental Sync that runs for the User Profile Service daily, isn't properly syncing the information between AD and Sharepoint.

An example of this can be a user's photo not syncing from Sharepoint -> AD, or a disabled user not disappearing from AD -> Sharepoint.

If I go into Central Administration and manually run a Full Sync, all the issues clear up and everything is properly in sync.

I can confirm that the Incremental Sync job is running every day as Central Admin reports a last run time.

FIM reports the following error for all my users:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException: Exception while trying to migrate user 'domain\username' to 'domain\username'. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The user does not exist or is not unique. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x81020054): The user does not exist or is not unique.

Has anyone got any ideas on why this would be happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to migrate users? Or have you recently migrated users? It looks like something is running or has ran move-spuser here.... That is very odd!

Answer (score 0):

Is this 2010/2013?
Have you recently patched the farm?
Have you checked your ULS logs?

Try using the FIM client to see if it's throwing any errors. You'll need to run it when the incremental sync is running.

You can find the client here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info.  Sharepoint 2010, I patched the farm a few months back which may have introduced the bug but I've only just become aware of it.  DS_DELTAIMPORT shows success.  MOSS_DELTAIMPORT shows success.  DS_EXPORT and MOSS_EXPORT show ma-extension errors.  See my edited post above for details.